# DualShock 4 wireless controller not working

Tags: ps4, controllers

I bought a PS4 and a DualShock 4 controller, and when I turned on the power button it told me to press the PS button. When I do, the controller, connected using the USB cable, just blinks blue and goes back to power off. I tried resetting the controller, but nothing happened.

What is going on, and what can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: I know it's a silly question but is the controller charged?

Answer (score 0):

Try hard-resetting (or unplugging) the PS4 with the controller connected via USB cable and then turn back on. My controllers get un-paired once in a while, and this always does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you just bought both, *have you gone through the pairing sequence yet*?

With the controller plugged into the console via the USB cable, click the power button on the controller. Out of the box, the controller is not tied to any specific PS4. Once you power on while linked with a USB your controller is now tethered.

Think of it as the "enter a PIN" part of syncing two Bluetooth devices.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure to charge it first because it does not come charged out of the box.